# Why does the "write enable" in QSPI with Macronix MX25L51245G always return WEL = 0?

Tags: stm32, spi, flash, qspi

I come to you to ask for help with Macronix MX25L51245G interfaced with STM32L476RG.

My QSPI is set to 32MHz.

Here what I do:

- QSPI Reset (0x66 - 0x99)
- SPI Reset (0x66 - 0x99)
- Wait for WIP = 0 (SPI)
- Enter in QPI (0x35) 1 line
- Wait for QUADEN = 1 and WIP = 0 in QSPI
- QSPI Read Status register (0x05)
- Write enable in QSPI (0x06)
- Wait for WEL = 1 and it never appends (register always return 0x64) in QSPI

If this has already happened to someone, I would like your feedback.

My code :

````c
//qspi_drv.c

#include "qspi_drv.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static uint8_t QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi,
        uint32_t Timeout);
static uint8_t QSPI_Configure_Dummy(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);
static uint8_t QSPI_EnterMemory_QPI(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);
static uint8_t QSPI_ResetMemory(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);
static uint8_t QSPI_EnterFourBytesAddress(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);
static uint8_t QSPI_OutDrvStrengthCfg(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);
static uint8_t QSPI_WriteEnable(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi);

QSPI_HandleTypeDef hqspi;

__IO uint8_t rx_complete = 0;
__IO uint8_t tx_complete = 0;

uint8_t opening_root_dir = 0;

uint8_t qspi_init_state = 0;

uint8_t QSPI_Driver_init() {

    hqspi.Instance = QUADSPI;

    if (HAL_QSPI_DeInit(&hqspi) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    HAL_QSPI_MspInit(&hqspi);

    hqspi.Init.ClockPrescaler = 0;
    hqspi.Init.FifoThreshold = 16;
    hqspi.Init.SampleShifting = QSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_HALFCYCLE;
    hqspi.Init.FlashSize = POSITION_VAL(QSPI_FLASH_SIZE) - 1;
    hqspi.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = QSPI_CS_HIGH_TIME_1_CYCLE;
    hqspi.Init.ClockMode = QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Init(&hqspi) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    if (QSPI_ResetMemory(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }

    /* Put QSPI memory in QPI mode */
    if (QSPI_EnterMemory_QPI(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }

    /* Set the QSPI memory in 4-bytes address mode */
    //if (QSPI_EnterFourBytesAddress(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
    //  return QSPI_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    //}
    /* Configuration of the dummy cycles on QSPI memory side */
    if (QSPI_Configure_Dummy(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }

    /* Configuration of the Output driver strength on memory side */
    if (QSPI_OutDrvStrengthCfg(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }
    qspi_init_state = 1;
    return QSPI_OK;
}

uint8_t QSPI_isInit() {
    return qspi_init_state;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_Configure_Dummy(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    uint8_t reg[2];

    /* Initialize the reading of status register */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.NbData = 1;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, QSPI_COMMAND_TIMEOUT) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(_hqspi, &(reg[0]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    sCommand.Instruction = READ_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, QSPI_COMMAND_TIMEOUT) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(_hqspi, &(reg[1]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Enable write operations ---------------------------------------- */
    if (QSPI_WriteEnable(_hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Write Volatile Configuration register (with new dummy cycles) -- */
    sCommand.Instruction = WRITE_STATUS_CONFIG_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.NbData = 2;

    MODIFY_REG(reg[1], MX25L512_CR_NB_DUMMY,
            (MX25L512_DUMMY_CYCLES_READ_QUAD << POSITION_VAL(MX25L512_CR_NB_DUMMY))); //Dummy cycle 10

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, QSPI_COMMAND_TIMEOUT) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit(_hqspi, &(reg[0]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    HAL_Delay(40);
    return QSPI_OK;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_EnterMemory_QPI(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    memset(&sConfig, 0, sizeof(QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef));

    /* Enable QPI operations ------------------------------------------ */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
    sCommand.Instruction = QPI_ENABLE_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for QPI enabling ---- */
    sConfig.Match = MX25L512_SR_QUADEN;
    sConfig.Mask = MX25L512_SR_QUADEN | MX25L512_SR_WIP;
    sConfig.MatchMode = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
    sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
    sConfig.Interval = 0x10;
    sConfig.AutomaticStop = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;

    if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(_hqspi, &sCommand, &sConfig,
    HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_ResetMemory(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    memset(&sConfig, 0, sizeof(QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef));
    uint8_t reg = 0;

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = RESET_ENABLE_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Send the reset memory command */
    sCommand.Instruction = RESET_MEMORY_CMD;
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Send command RESET command in SPI mode */
    /* Initialize the reset enable command */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
    sCommand.Instruction = RESET_ENABLE_CMD;
    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }
    /* Send the reset memory command */
    sCommand.Instruction = RESET_MEMORY_CMD;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* After reset CMD, 1000ms requested if QSPI memory SWReset occured during full chip erase operation */
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait the WIP bit=0 */
    sConfig.Match = 0;
    sConfig.Mask = MX25L512_SR_WIP;
    sConfig.MatchMode = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
    sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
    sConfig.Interval = 0x10;
    sConfig.AutomaticStop = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;

    if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(_hqspi, &sCommand, &sConfig,
    HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* 40ms  Write Status/Configuration Register Cycle Time */
    HAL_Delay(40);

    return QSPI_OK;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_EnterFourBytesAddress(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));

    /* Initialize the command */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = ENTER_4_BYTE_ADDR_MODE_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Enable write operations */
    if (QSPI_WriteEnable(_hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait the memory is ready */
    if (QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(_hqspi,
    HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_WriteEnable(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;

    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    memset(&sConfig, 0, sizeof(QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef));

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = WRITE_ENABLE_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    sConfig.Match = MX25L512_SR_WREN;
    sConfig.Mask = MX25L512_SR_WREN;
    sConfig.MatchMode = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
    sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
    sConfig.Interval = 0x10;
    sConfig.AutomaticStop = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(_hqspi, &sCommand, &sConfig,
    HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

static uint8_t QSPI_OutDrvStrengthCfg(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    uint8_t reg[2];

    /* Initialize the reading of status register */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.NbData = 1;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Configure the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Reception of the data */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(_hqspi, &(reg[0]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Initialize the reading of configuration register */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_VOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.NbData = 1;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Configure the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Reception of the data */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(_hqspi, &(reg[1]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Enable write operations */
    if (QSPI_WriteEnable(_hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Update the configuration register with new output driver strength */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = WRITE_STATUS_CONFIG_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.NbData = 2;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Set Output Strength of the QSPI memory 15 ohms */
    MODIFY_REG(reg[1], 0x07, (0x06 << POSITION_VAL(0x07)));

    /* Configure the write volatile configuration register command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(_hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Transmission of the data */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit(_hqspi, &(reg[0]), HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

void HAL_QSPI_RxCpltCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi) {
    rx_complete = 1;
}

uint8_t QSPI_Driver_read(uint8_t *buff, uint32_t address, uint32_t size) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = QUAD_INOUT_FAST_READ_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_4_LINES;
    sCommand.AddressSize = QSPI_ADDRESS_32_BITS;
    sCommand.Address = address;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = DUMMY_CLOCK_CYCLES_READ_QUAD;
    sCommand.NbData = size;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    rx_complete = 0;
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive_DMA(&hqspi, buff) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_STATUS_ERROR;
    }
    while (!rx_complete)
        ;

    return QSPI_OK;
}

uint8_t QSPI_GetStatus(void) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    uint8_t reg;

    /* Initialize the read flag status register command */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.NbData = 1;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Configure the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Reception of the data */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(&hqspi, &reg, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Check the value of the register*/
    if ((reg & 0x01) == 0) {
        return QSPI_OK;
    } else {
        return QSPI_BUSY;
    }
}

static uint8_t QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *_hqspi,
        uint32_t Timeout) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef sConfig;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    memset(&sConfig, 0, sizeof(QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef));

    /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for memory ready ------ */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = READ_STATUS_REG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    sConfig.Match = 0x00;
    sConfig.Mask = MX25L512_SR_WIP;
    sConfig.MatchMode = QSPI_MATCH_MODE_AND;
    sConfig.StatusBytesSize = 1;
    sConfig.Interval = 0x10;
    sConfig.AutomaticStop = QSPI_AUTOMATIC_STOP_ENABLE;

    if (HAL_QSPI_AutoPolling(_hqspi, &sCommand, &sConfig, Timeout) != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

void HAL_QSPI_TimeOutCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi) {
    Error_Handler();
}

void HAL_QSPI_ErrorCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi) {
    Error_Handler();
}

uint8_t QSPI_Erase_Chip(void) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));

    /* Initialize the erase command */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = BULK_ERASE_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Enable write operations */
    if (QSPI_WriteEnable(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for end of erase */
    if (QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&hqspi,
    MX25L512_BULK_ERASE_MAX_TIME) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

uint8_t QSPI_Driver_eraze_subsector(uint32_t address) {

    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));

    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = SUBSECTOR_ERASE_4_BYTE_ADDR_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_4_LINES;
    sCommand.AddressSize = QSPI_ADDRESS_32_BITS;
    sCommand.Address = address;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    if (QSPI_WriteEnable(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    if (QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&hqspi,
    MX25L512_SUBSECTOR_ERASE_MAX_TIME) != QSPI_OK) {
        return QSPI_ERROR;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

uint8_t QSPI_Driver_eraze(uint32_t address, uint32_t size) {

    uint32_t start_address = address;
    uint32_t erased_size = 0;
    while (erased_size < size) {
        if (QSPI_Driver_eraze_subsector(start_address) != QSPI_OK) {
            return QSPI_ERROR;
        }
        erased_size += QSPI_SUBSECTOR_SIZE;
        start_address += QSPI_SUBSECTOR_SIZE;
    }

    return QSPI_OK;
}

void HAL_QSPI_TxCpltCallback(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi) {
    tx_complete = 1;
}

uint8_t QSPI_Driver_write(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t address, uint32_t size) {
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;
    memset(&sCommand, 0, sizeof(QSPI_CommandTypeDef));
    uint32_t end_addr, current_size, current_addr;

    /* Calculation of the size between the write address and the end of the page */
    current_size = QSPI_PAGE_SIZE - (address % QSPI_PAGE_SIZE);

    /* Check if the size of the data is less than the remaining place in the page */
    if (current_size > size) {
        current_size = size;
    }

    /* Initialize the address variables */
    current_addr = address;
    end_addr = address + size;

    /* Initialize the program command */
    sCommand.InstructionMode = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.Instruction = EXT_QUAD_IN_FAST_PROG_CMD;
    sCommand.AddressMode = QSPI_ADDRESS_4_LINES;
    sCommand.AddressSize = QSPI_ADDRESS_32_BITS;
    sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
    sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
    sCommand.DdrMode = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    sCommand.SIOOMode = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Perform the write page by page */
    do {
        sCommand.Address = current_addr;
        sCommand.NbData = current_size;

        /* Enable write operations */
        if (QSPI_WriteEnable(&hqspi) != QSPI_OK) {
            return QSPI_ERROR;
        }

        /* Configure the command */
        if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)
                != HAL_OK) {
            return QSPI_ERROR;
        }

        /* Transmission of the data */
        tx_complete = 0;
        if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit_DMA(&hqspi, buf) != HAL_OK) {
            return QSPI_ERROR;
        }
        while (!tx_complete)
            ;

        /* Configure automatic polling mode to wait for end of program */
        if (QSPI_AutoPollingMemReady(&hqspi,
        HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != QSPI_OK) {
            return QSPI_ERROR;
        }

        /* Update the address and size variables for next page programming */
        current_addr += current_size;
        buf += current_size;
        current_size =
                ((current_addr + QSPI_PAGE_SIZE) > end_addr) ?
                        (end_addr - current_addr) : QSPI_PAGE_SIZE;
    } while (current_addr < end_addr);

    return QSPI_OK;
}

```
````

Comment: This is a question and answer site. What is your question and, bear in mind that asking whether someone has done this is not a valid question. But you could easily turn this into a valid question by posting what the timing diagram is in the data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry for that. I tried to turn it into a valid question !